# Change column width in dataGridView - C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, width

I want to change the column width manually in a datagridview. What should I do? Should I change the code in designer.cs or just in .cs?

I have added something in the code but it doesn't work:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 200;
```

Here's my code:

```
private void sqlConnResident()
        {
            BindingSource dbBindSource = new BindingSource();

            SqlCommand com;
            com = new SqlCommand();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCon);

            com.Connection = con;
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.CommandText = "view_penghuni";

            SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(com);

            IDCabang = new SqlParameter();
            IDCabang.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
            IDCabang.Size = 5;
            IDCabang.ParameterName = "@IDCabang";
            IDCabang.Value = IDCabangC;
            IDCabang.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            com.Parameters.Add(IDCabang);

            con.Open();

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            dataAdapter.Fill(table);
            dbBindSource.DataSource = table;

            //dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);
            // you can make it grid readonly.
            dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
            // finally bind the data to the grid
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dbBindSource;
            //this doesn't work
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 200;
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 200;

            con.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove from your code:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 200;
dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 200;
```

and add to constructor of your Form:

```
Load += Form1_Load;
```

where `Form1_Load` is:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 200;
    dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 200;
}
```

Comment: RoutedEventArgs appears as an error, should I change it into another?

Comment: Should I add `Load += Form1_Load;` in the `sqlConnResident`? I've tried it but the column width still won't change.

Comment: Add 'Load += Form1_Load;' to your constructor in Form class